# vncviewer: VNC server closed connection

Tags: debian, kde, vnc

So I installed a VNC server (Tight VNC) on my workstation 'orac' which is running Debian Jessie with KDE Plasma. And a VNC client (also Tight VNC) on my workstation 'tact' running Debian Stretch with KDE Plasma.

I ran vncpasswd on orac to configure the password.

I want to use VNC to use 'orac' from 'tact'.

From tact I ssh'ed to orac and started the vncserver:

```
jj5@orac:~$ vncserver 

New 'X' desktop is orac:1

Starting applications specified in /home/jj5/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/jj5/.vnc/orac:1.log
```

Then from a console on tact I ran:

```
jj5@tact:~$ vncviewer orac:1
Connected to RFB server, using protocol version 3.8
Enabling TightVNC protocol extensions
Performing standard VNC authentication
Password: 
Authentication successful
Desktop name "jj5's X desktop (orac:1)"
VNC server default format:
  32 bits per pixel.
  Least significant byte first in each pixel.
  True colour: max red 255 green 255 blue 255, shift red 16 green 8 blue 0
Using default colormap which is TrueColor.  Pixel format:
  32 bits per pixel.
  Least significant byte first in each pixel.
  True colour: max red 255 green 255 blue 255, shift red 16 green 8 blue 0
vncviewer: VNC server closed connection
```

Before `vncviewer: VNC server closed connection` is reported everything seems to be working smoothly. A window opens, I see KDE Plasma doing it's login/loading thing, then my orac desktop loads, a bunch of default Dolphin windows load, and KDE Plasma starts processing my autostart scripts, so everything seems to be working fine, and then almost as soon as it starts KDE/VNC disappears and shuts down usually with `vncviewer: VNC server closed connection` but sometimes with `vncviewer: read: Connection reset by peer` instead.

So why is KDE (or VNC?) bailing just as soon as it starts? Any help greatly appreciated!

p.s. here's some extra info about the environment on the VNC server (orac):

```
jj5@orac:~/.vnc$ ls -al
total 24K
drwx------  2 jj5 jj5 4.0K May  4 17:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 74 jj5 jj5 4.0K May  4 17:35 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 jj5 jj5 1.3K May  4 17:36 orac:1.log
-rw-r--r--  1 jj5 jj5    5 May  4 17:35 orac:1.pid
-rw-------  1 jj5 jj5    8 May  4 15:52 passwd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jj5 jj5  263 May  4 17:32 xstartup*
```

And the log file says:

```
jj5@orac:~/.vnc$ cat orac\:1.log 
04/05/17 17:35:57 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
04/05/17 17:35:57 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
04/05/17 17:35:57 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
04/05/17 17:35:57 All Rights Reserved.
04/05/17 17:35:57 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
04/05/17 17:35:57 Desktop name 'X' (orac:1)
04/05/17 17:35:57 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
04/05/17 17:35:57 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5901

04/05/17 17:36:04 Got connection from client 10.1.1.126
04/05/17 17:36:04 Using protocol version 3.8
04/05/17 17:36:04 Enabling TightVNC protocol extensions
04/05/17 17:36:06 Full-control authentication passed by 10.1.1.126
04/05/17 17:36:06 Pixel format for client 10.1.1.126:
04/05/17 17:36:06   32 bpp, depth 24, little endian
04/05/17 17:36:06   true colour: max r 255 g 255 b 255, shift r 16 g 8 b 0
04/05/17 17:36:06   no translation needed
04/05/17 17:36:06 Using tight encoding for client 10.1.1.126
04/05/17 17:36:06 Using compression level 1 for client 10.1.1.126
04/05/17 17:36:06 Using image quality level 6 for client 10.1.1.126
04/05/17 17:36:06 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 10.1.1.126
04/05/17 17:36:06 Enabling cursor position updates for client 10.1.1.126
04/05/17 17:36:06 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 10.1.1.126
```

Note that 10.1.1.126 is my VNC client 'tact'.

My xstartup script is pretty much just the default one (I don't have an ~/.Xresources file so I removed that from the xrdb command, otherwise it's as-is):

```
jj5@orac:~/.vnc$ cat xstartup 
#!/bin/sh

#xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xrdb
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow. So I found the issue and fixed it like this:

```
jj5@orac:~$ rm .config/autostart/dropbox.desktop
```

The dropbox.desktop file seems to have been installed when I tried to install the Dropbox client on my system (but I had trouble getting it to work and don't use it). I had forgotten this file was here. I figured it out by looking at recently modified files/directories in my home directory after trying to access orac via VNC. E.g.:

```
jj5@orac:~$ ls -Alt | head
total 21292
drwx------    4 jj5  jj5      4096 May  4 18:12 Dropbox
drwx------    5 jj5  jj5      4096 May  4 18:12 .dropbox
drwx------    2 jj5  jj5      4096 May  4 18:12 .vnc
-rw-------    1 jj5  jj5      3136 May  4 18:12 .Xauthority
-rw-------    1 jj5  jj5     26860 May  4 18:07 .viminfo
-rw-------    1 jj5  jj5      6692 May  4 17:49 .bash_history
drwx------    2 jj5  jj5      4096 May  4 17:36 .pulse
-rw-r--r--    1 jj5  jj5        75 May  4 17:25 .selected_editor
-rw-r--r--    1 jj5  jj5       697 May  4 17:22 .profile
-rw-r--r--    1 jj5  jj5      3963 May  4 17:22 .bashrc
```

The dropbox.desktop file looked like this:

```
jj5@orac:~/archive/2017-05-04-181328$ cat dropbox.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=dropbox start -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```